# Can I go back to default color scheme?

Tags: windows

I hit something (not on purpose) in personalize and now I have a funky horrible color scheme.

Is there a way to default back to my computer's original color scheme?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Yes, You Can! Just tell us which Windows version?

Answer (score 0):

If it's all black and purple, that's the "High Contrast" mode. According to [this MS page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/ece8e1d7-1a7c-473c-a0f4-3c9d66fee295/turn-high-contrast-mode-on-or-off-in-windows), you can turn it off using <kbd>Left Alt</kbd><kbd>Left Shift</kbd><kbd>Print Screen</kbd>, or by searching the Start menu for "high contrast" and using the settings there.